# Cygwin - awk-Cannot allocate memory

Tags: awk

while using `Cygwin ( CYGWIN_NT-6.1 )`, to compare two files `(file11.csv : 25.82 Mn rows, file22.csv : 4.1 Mn)` ,

```
executing the Command awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next
}{print (a[$1]?a[$1]:"NotFound,NotFound") "," $0}' file11.csv file22.csv>Op_file33.csv
```

I am getting this error :

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR= fatal: more_nodes: nextfree: can't allocate 4000 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory),
```

. Error File (gawk.exe.stackdump) contains:Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
002299A0  7710F003  (00000118, 0000EA60, 00000000, 00229AD4)
002299B4  7710EFB2  (00000118, 0000EA60, 000000A4, 00229AB0)
00229AD4  610DBE29  (00000000, 00000000, 00229AD0, 00229BC4)
00229BC4  610D915E  (00000000, 61102FA2, 003B0023, 00230000)
00229C24  610D962E  (20000038, 00000000, 00229C64, 00000006)
00229CD4  610D9780  (00000500, 00000006, 00229D04, 0022CE64)
00229CF4  610D97AC  (00000006, 0022CE80, 0022CE64, 0042DA60)
00229D24  610D9A85  (0044F0F4, 00000503, 00000000, 00000000)
00229D44  0042B773  (00000004, 00000001, 00229E64, 6103118A)
00229D54  691013B2  (0000000B, 00229DB8, 00000000, 00000000)
00229E64  6103118A  (00000118, 0000EA60, 000000A4, 00229F60)
00229F84  610DBEE2  (00000004, 0022A060, 0000001C, 00000000)
0022A094  610314F0  (0022A180, 0022FF14, 0022A19C, 0022A154)
0022A0B8  77AE65F9  (0022A180, 0022FF14, 0022A19C, 0022A154)
0022A168  77AE65CB  (0022A180, 0022A19C, 0022A180, 0022A19C)
0022A498  77AE6457  (00000000, 00000000, 0022A4DC, 77AF3B27)
End of stack trace (more stack frames may be present)

Answer (score 1):

You're currently storing the much larger file (file11.csv = 25M lines) in memory rather than the smaller file (file22.csv = 4M lines).

Just change your logic to store the file22 and compare that to the lines in file11 as you read them you'll probably be fine.

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton , I did the same before posting here, the command was running more than 30 hours, didn't get any output, where as the same command is running for <2 Mn rows within 5 mins,  any other suggestions would help

Comment: How about just selecting the key fields and line numbers, doing the comparison on that and then using the output line numbers to select lines to print from the real files? That'd save you storing the full line for one of the files.